# Why is Thread.stop() so dangerous

Tags: java, multithreading

Why is `Thread.stop()` so dangerous?

Why is it advisable to use `Thread.interrupted()` instead?

I know `stop` is deprecated. What other thing makes it unsafe?

Is there any place where I can use `stop` method? If so give me an example.

Comment: Did you read http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html as linked from the Thread.stop javadocs?

Comment: +1, my hand did the upvote whilst my brain was contemplating none :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is Thread.stop() so dangerous?

The problems are described in detail here:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

> Why is it advisable to use Thread.interrupted() instead?

Because `Thread.interrupt()` lets the *target thread* of the interrupt respond when it reaches a point when it knows it is *safe* to do so.

> I know stop is deprecated. What other thing makes it unsafe?

See link above.

> Is there any place where I can use stop method? If so give me an example.

In theory, if you knew that the thread you were stopping:

- didn't ever update data structures shared with other threads,
- didn't use wait/notify or higher level synchronization classes, or classes that depended on them,
- and possibly a few other things.

For example, I think it would be safe to `stop()` this thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){for (long l = 0; l > 0; l++){}}).start();
```

However, in most cases it is *too difficult* to do the analysis to figure out if calling `stop()` will really be safe.  For instance, you have to analyse every possible bit of code (including core and 3rd-party libraries) that the thread uses.  So that makes it unsafe by default.

Comment: +1: The problem with using stop() is that it only works safely with well behaved, well understood, simple threads, however if its well behaved you shouldn't need to use stop().