# Aborting evaluation in Rust after a timeout

Tags: rust, timeout

I have a function in Rust (that I did not write) which either returns in milliseconds or grinds for ~10 minutes before failing.

I would like to wrap the call to this function in something that returns an `Option` which is `None` if it takes over 10 seconds to run, and contains the result if it took less time to run. However I haven't been able to find any way to interrupt the evaluation of this function once it has been called.

For example:

```
// This is the unpredictable function
fn f() {
    // Wait randomly for between 0 and 10 seconds
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(rng.gen_range(0, 10)));
}

fn main() {
    for _ in 0..100 {
        // Run f() here but so that the whole loop takes no more than 100 seconds
        // by aborting f() if it takes longer than 1 second
    }
}
```

I have found some methods that might work using futures with timeouts, but I would like to minimize overhead, and I am not sure how expensive it would be to create a future for every call to this function given that it will be called so many times.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way in Rust to create a timeout for a thread or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181719/what-is-the-correct-way-in-rust-to-create-a-timeout-for-a-thread-or-a-function)

Comment: @SCappella I saw that thread but I don't think it quite answers my case because that involves spawning entire threads, which is far too expensive for what I am doing. I think Peter's solution below though solves this by using futures instead of threads.

Comment: Alternatively, just solve the halting problem /s (Obviously kidding). This is a very well written question, @user42257.

Answer (score 4):

The overhead of asynchronous execution is likely to be minimal, especially since your function runs in at least milliseconds, which is already very slow.

Something like this will work:

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::timeout;

async fn f() -> i32 {
    // Wait randomly for between 0 and 10 seconds
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    tokio::time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(rng.gen_range(0, 10))).await;
    // return something
    1000
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    for _ in 0..100 {
        if let Ok(result) = timeout(Duration::from_secs(1), f()).await {
            println!("result = {}", result);
        } else {
            // took too long
        }
    }
}
```

---

As ever with performance, if you are concerned that one particular approach could be slow, test the theory rather than assuming you're right. Performance characteristics can often be surprising.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it still appears to be willing to wait for more than 1 second between printing "result = 1000". That is, I don't think the timeout is actually aborting the evaluation and the else statement is never run.

Comment: @user42257 `thread::sleep` is a blocking operation, so shouldn't be used in an `async` function. That's why this doesn't work right. Your function is probably also blocking, so threads are the only option. Unless your function was designed for `async` use, it just blocks the whole thread.

Comment: @SCappella Ah, I didn't know that tokio::time::timeout had that restriction. I'll look into how to do this with threads starting with the link you recommended before.

Comment: My bad! I blindly copied OP's code, and didn't test. I've updated my answer now.