# kill function after certain time in rust

Tags: rust

I have a function that try to call some services, one of them ( external service) have a lot of issues, and never give any answers and I would like to kill it after certain time.

I would like to find any crate that could set a timeout calling a function. But I can't manage to find one ?

```
fn main() {
    let result = retry::retry(Fixed::from_millis(3000).take(5), || {
            let possibly_return = function_maybe_never_return();
        match possibly_return {
            Ok(kubeconfig) => OperationResult::Ok(kubeconfig),
            Err(err) => Err(err)
        }
    });
    match result {
            Ok(downloaded) => info!("OK !!")
            Err(e) => Error!("Unable to ... after many retries {:?}", e),
    };
}

fn function_maybe_never_return(){
    
}
```

I want to use retry crate on it to retrying operation.

Comment: You cannot kill a function.

Comment: yes, I know, but do you have any workarround ?

Comment: You can run the process on a seperate thread [and terminate it after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181719/what-is-the-correct-way-in-rust-to-create-a-timeout-for-a-thread-or-a-function)

Comment: You can use `std::process::Command` to spawn an external process (possibly the program you're running with a special command-line flag that tells it to run the function) and terminate it after a timeout. That is the only portable way of achieving your goal.

Comment: You can kill a process so perhaps run one.

Comment: Hi @maathor. If you can change the function then it should be possible to make it async and use one of existing libraries to make your call to external service async as well. The it'll be much easier to cancel function execution. Please let me know if you are interested in that kind of solution then I can provide you more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an async runtime like tokio, you can.
I had a similar requirement. I had a blocking function which I need to cancel after a set timeout. Here's how I did it.

```
fn long_running_function() -> Result<()> {
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1000));
    Ok(())
}

async fn call_long_running_function() {
    tokio::time::timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(2), tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move ||long_running_function())).await.unwrap()

}
```

Here, the long running blocking function will be called inside a `tokio::spawn_blocking` which is further wrapped in a `tokio::time::timeout()`, so when that deadline exceeds, the `long_running_function` will die with a Deadline error.

I'm sure there are other better ways too. This is how I had it working for my use case, as I was already working on async code base.