# Sikuli, Java, and java.lang.ThreadDeath exception

Tags: exception, sikuli, java

we are using Sikuli with Java (Sikuli 1.1.1), but we are running into java.lang.ThreadDeath exception for a new client. In Java Configuration, we have selected mix code of Enable - hide warning and run with protections. Has anyone run into this issue before and what is the reason and possible fix?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in the code `Thread.stop()` is being called.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) don't do this! It releases all locks held by that thread may cause locked objects to be accessed in inconsistent state.

Comment: See also [Why is Thread.stop() so dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218969/why-is-thread-stop-so-dangerous)